# Create a function to automatically build specific plots in R

Tags: r

I have the following R code that builds two plots, one with the six line types and the other with the 25 point types for plots in R. I like to use these plots as a reference for when I am building other plots in R. How can I write a function called `pointslines` that automatically runs the code for me? This is the code I use to build the plots

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2),pty="s",mai=c(0.5,.4,.4,.5))
plot(1:25,1:25,type="n")
for (i in 1:25) points(i,i,pch=i,cex=.7)
title("The 25 pch symbols")

plot(1:6,1:6,type="n")
for(i in 1:6) lines(c(1,6),c(i,i),lty=i,lwd=2)
title("The 6 lty line types")
```

I basically want to just be able to enter `pointslines()` into the console and have it run the code above.

Comment: Your current code doesn't seem to have any variables that need to change from call to call, so you would just need to wrap the whole thing up in `pointslines = function() { <your code> }` - is there any specific issue you're having with creating the function?

Comment: @r2evans - it all goes in one plot because of `par(mfrow=c(1,2))`

Comment: @Marius That worked thank you!

Comment: Oops, yup, duh. Don't judge, @thelatemail, distracted/tired ...